# Execute MongoDB Eval function from C# driver (MongoDB version 2.4)

Tags: c#, mongodb

After updating my DB version from 2.2 to 2.4 I've found that I couldn't execute Database.Eval() function from my C# code because "I don't have permissions to perform my task". After some investigation I've discovered that there were some changes in MongoDB:

> With authentication enabled, db.eval() will fail during the operation if you do not have the permission to perform a specified task.
>   Changed in version 2.4: You must have full admin access to run.

http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.eval/

Can you advise me on how to specify those admin rights in my C# code?

Update 1:
I didn't mention that I'm using login:password at the start of my connection string and the user is in the following roles: roles: [ "readWrite", "dbAdmin" ] } I'm also using the MongoHQ db hosting.

Comment: After setting up a user that has admin rights, you can append the username and password to the connection string like so `var connectionString = "mongodb://admin:password@localhost"`.

Answer (score 1):

You have to add the righst (dbAdmin role, userAdmin role, clusterAdmin role) to your connection string user.

1- check your user on the connection string

mongodb://[username:password@]host1[:port1]...

2- Create the user with the admin role `db.addUser( { user: "<user>", pwd: "<password>", roles: [<roles>] } )`

see 
http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/user-privileges/
http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.addUser/

Comment: Please see the Update 1